# MSMQ cannot connect to remote server exception and receiving send failure

Tags: msmq

I've wrote a sample c# program to send/receive messages. To connect I use this:

.\Private$\NeilQueue

the queue exists and it works find.

The computer in question's name is WORKST5377

So I tried to connect using this string:

FORMATNAME:DIRECT=OS:WORKST5377\Private$\NeilQueue

But I get an exception of remote computer is not available when I try to retrieve the message. However, I don't get any error when I call Send()

Is there something wrong with my connection string or is it something as simple as I cannot do this for the machine it is running on? I haven't got a remote computer to test on now, I just want to ensure the connection works using the proper connection string.

Also, how do you tell if a message was actually sent to the queue? I tried:

```
mm.AcknowledgeType = AcknowledgeTypes.NegativeReceive;
mm.UseDeadLetterQueue = true;
mm.TimeToReachQueue = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
mm.UseJournalQueue = true;
```

but nothing was put in the journal queue. It only did a negative when I set UseDeadLetterQueue - or is this how you do it?

thanks.

Comment: To be clear the WORKST5377 exists and has msmq installed on it?